# What's wrong with this Bitvise Tunnelier SFTP command?

Tags: powershell, sftp

I'm trying to put together an SFTP command to be run through Powershell. The executable I have access to is SFTPC.exe (Bitvise Tunnelier)

The command I'm trying is

```
sftpc.exe user@ftp.domain.com -pw=password -unat=y -cmd="ls \"somefile.txt\""
```

According to the documentation at https://www.bitvise.com/files/sftpc-v4.14-usage.txt this should log in and run the command `ls "somefile.txt"` (quotes are escaped within the command parameter)

What actually happens is that I get another line for input, as if there's an unclosed quote.

I've tried adding an extra quote to the end

```
sftpc.exe user@ftp.domain.com -pw=password -unat=y -cmd="ls \"somefile.txt\"""
```

This connects and logs in, but the colland it tries to run is `ls \somefile.txt"`

Note the trailing quote and the leading slash.

So it looks like I'm missing something in the quote escaping, but I can't see what I might be doing wrong. I've also tried replacing double quotes with single in a couple of different places, experiments that usually end in a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape character in powershell is not a backslash, it's the backtick.

Does the below work?

```
sftpc.exe user@ftp.domain.com -pw=password -unat=y -cmd="ls `"somefile.txt`""
```

Comment: @arco444 Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072330/how-can-i-set-in-the-bitvise-ssh-client-the-tunnel-automatic-connect-if-open-wi